# Python assignment(or Binding) example

Tags: python, assign

```
#First
x = 9
y = x
x = 18
print(y)

#Second
S = {1,3,4,5,6}
T = S
T.remove(5)
print(S)
```

First : The result is 9 
Second : The result is {1,3,4,6}

At the first, the y is not changed by x's change.
At the second, the S is changed by T's change.
I wanna know the reason.
Thank you in advance! =)

Comment: Reut is correct.  If you want to demonstrate the difference between mutable and immutable objects, you need to modify x rather than completely reassign it.  Your comment hints that you understand this, so what is your question?

Answer (score 10):

This is a very common question. For Python, it's helpful to read [this section of the language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types).

In short, in Python, you have names bound to objects.

In your first example you bind to the name `x` the object whose value is the integer 9. Then you bind to `y` that same object. Next you bind to `x` the object whose value is the integer 18. The object bound to `y` is still the one with the value 9, so 9 is printed.

In your second example, you bind a set object to `S`. Then you bind *that same object* to `T`. The code `T.remove(5)` *mutates the object bound to T, which is the same object bound to S*. That is why when you inspect `S`, you see the change that made through `T`, because the names `S` and `T` were bound to exactly the same object.

In pictures:

```
x = 9

    x -----------> 9

y = x

    x -----------> 9
                   ^
                   |
    y -------------+

x = 18

    x -----------> 18

    y ------------> 9
```

See `y` did not change. Why not? Because I bound `x` to a new object. But I did not change what `y` was bound to. Now let's look at the second example

```
S = {1, 3, 4, 5, 6}

    S -----------> 1 3 4 5 6

T = S

    S -----------> 1 3 4 5 6
                   ^
                   |
    T -------------+

T.remove(5)

    S -----------> 1 3 4 6
                   ^
                   |
    T -------------+
```

The object bound to `S` changes. Note I did not say that `S` changed! I never changed the bindings; `S` and `T` still point to the same object. It is very important to understand the difference between the names and the objects bound to them.

Also note, I did not say the word "variable." :)

Answer (score 1):

you start with `x` as an reference to object with the value 9, then `y` as a reference to the same object as `x`. after you assign `x` to a new object with the value 18, `x` now refers to a different object but `y` still refers to the same object with the value 9.